# How to rotate D3 Chart XAxis label in vertical

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, dc.js

I'm using AngularJS, Blur Admin UI and D3 chart. With help of these I have created the PIE, BAR & ROW charts.

I have a lot of data in BAR chart x-axis and one x-axis label overlapping with other labels. Now, I'm trying to show the x-axis label as vertically.
But i didn't get the solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" ba-panel
    ba-panel-title="BAR Chart" ba-panel-class="with-scroll">
    <div id="state-donations" class=" "></div>
</div>
```

**Controller.JS**

```
BarTypeChart
    .width(450)
    .height(300)
    .colors(barChartColors)
    .dimension(geoType)
    .group(typeOfGeo)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
    .centerBar(false)
    .gap(10)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(geoType))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .ordering(function(d){return d.value;})
    .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

Can anyone help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the examples from dc.js none of them have rotated text on the x-axis. And in D3 we also have to do it ourself

So you have to do it yourself after drawing the graph.

```
var bargraph = d3.select("#barchart"); // or some other method to get the svg of the chart
bargraph.select('.axis.x')
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
        .attr("dx", "-1em");
```

**Edit**

Found an example that dc.js has a `postRender` event. https://www.intothevoid.io/data-visualization/row-chart-axis-labels-dc-js/

```
BarTypeChart.on("postRender", function(chart) {
    chart.select('.axis.x')
         .attr("text-anchor", "end")
         .selectAll("text")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
         .attr("dy", "-0.7em")
         .attr("dx", "-1em");
  });
```

Comment: No idea why this is getting downvoted. Yes, you'll find many examples and previous answers here on SO which do just what you suggest. dc.js is no different from D3 in this. However I'd suggest the `pretransition` event rather than `postRender`, to avoid the jump.